# Create camera overlay to read OCR Code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, ocr

I am working an application which is using OCR code reading functionality, but i want to make a overlay on camera, like some portion of camera will read the code and other view on screen will show with blur effect.I am stuck here...please help...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomOverlay View and use it.

I did similar kind of demo app.
Please check here:https://github.com/RaviiOS/BarCodeScanDemo/tree/master/BarCodeScanDemo